# XPath/XSLT contains() for multiple strings

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Does `contains()` work for multiple words stored in a variable? Will the below one work? If it won't work, please help me with a solution.

```
<xsl:variable name="games" select="footballvolleyballchesscarrom"/>

<xsl:when test="contains($games,'chess,carrom')">CORRECT</xsl:when>
```

Comment: Your variable declaration isn't right. The string in `@select` must be quoted else would try to match an element with that name. Can you use XSLT-2.0? Using regular expressions for matching here would be simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're looking to do a **logical OR of substring containment**...

First of all, this `select` is likely wrong<sup>1</sup>:

```
<xsl:variable name="games" select="footballvolleyballchesscarrom"/>
```

It's looking for an element named `footballvolleyballchesscarrom`.  If you're trying to set games to the *string* `footballvolleyballchesscarrom`, change it to this:

```
<xsl:variable name="games" select="'footballvolleyballchesscarrom'"/>
```

Then, use either

### XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:when test="contains($games,'chess')
             or contains($games,'carrom')">CORRECT</xsl:when>
```

or

### XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:when test="matches($games,'chess|carrom')">CORRECT</xsl:when>
```

to test whether `$games` contains one of your multiple substrings.

---

<sup>1</sup> If you really intended to select (possibly multiple) elements from the input XML here, there is another XSLT 2.0 option for testing the selected sequence against a set of possible values.  If your input XML were, say,

```
<games>
  <game>football</game>
  <game>volleyball</game>
  <game>chess</game>
  <game>carrom</game>
</games>
```

then this template,

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="games" select="//game"/>
  <xsl:if test="$games = ('chess','carrom')">CORRECT</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

would output `CORRECT` because among the string values of the selected elements is at least one of `chess` or `carrom`.

Comment: Of course, if your intended meaning was that it must contain both words, then you can replace "or" with "and" in the first solution. You didn't actually say what your requirements were.

Comment: Let's hear it from the OP, Dr. Kay :)

Answer (score 1):

I think multiple variables will not work with contains method. As per the defination:

```
boolean contains(str1, str2)
```

str1 : A string that might contain the second argument.
str2:  A string that might be contained in the first argument.

Refer : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256195(v=vs.110).aspx

You can use or operator:

```
<xsl:when test="contains($games,'chess') or contains($games,'carrom')">CORRECT</xsl:when>
```